# Cyclic Dependencies in Template Class

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

I am having an issue with cyclic dependencies with template classes.  I have something similar to the following,

```
// A.hxx
template<typename T>
class B;

template<typename T>
class C;

template<typename T>
class A
{
    A(T const& x, T const& y, T const& z)
    {
        data[0] = x;
        data[1] = y;
        data[2] = z;
    }

    A(B<T> const& b) :
     A(b.x(),b.y(),b.z())
    {}

    A(C<T> const& c) :
     A(c.x(),c.y(),c.z())
    {}


    T x() {return data[0];}
    T y() {return data[1];}
    T z() {return data[2];}

    T data[3];
};



// B.hxx
template<typename T>
class A;

template<typename T>
class C;

template<typename T>
class B
{
    B(T const& y, T const& z, T const& x)
    {
        data[0] = y;
        data[1] = z;
        data[2] = x;
    }

    B(A<T> const& a) :
     B(a.y(),a.z(),a.x())
    {}

    B(C<T> const& c) :
     B(c.y(),c.z(),c.x())
    {}

    T x() {return data[2];}
    T y() {return data[0];}
    T z() {return data[1];}

    T data[3];
};



// C.hxx
template<typename T>
class A;

template<typename T>
class B;

template<typename T>
class C
{
    C(T const& z, T const& x, T const& y)
    {
        data[0] = z;
        data[1] = x;
        data[2] = y;
    }

    C(A<T> const& a) :
     C(a.z(),a.x(),a.y())
    {}

    C(B<T> const& b) :
     C(b.z(),b.x(),b.y())
    {}

    T x() {return data[1];}
    T y() {return data[2];}
    T z() {return data[0];}

    T data[3];
};
```

The forward declarations do not work.  I have tried breaking the definitions out of the declaration and including the relevant hxx file after declaring the class, but no luck either.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: can you put all 3 classes in the same header file ?

Comment: I noticed that when you actually define the classes, you forgot the semicolon after the closing brace. Might that be the issue?

Comment: Also, some of the delegated constructors seem wrong (i.e. the last `C` constructor using `ZXZ`). When I fixed those, I didn't have any issues with this code. Are you sure this matches what you're trying to do?

Comment: I originally used classex XYZ, YZX, and ZXY.  As pointed out in the first comment, that was hard to read and I even confused myself. I switched to classes A,B,C with a simple find/replace, but since I had typos it messed things up a little.  This should all be fixed now.  But still, that is not the issue, it is definitely a circular dependency issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the first solution that comes to mind: Define all three classes in the same header file. Declare the conversion constructors inside the classes, but don't provide a definition for them just yet. After all the classes are defined (at the bottom of the header file) provide an inline definition of the conversion constructors outside of all of the classes.

Slightly better, you can have three separate header files, one for each class, where you include the headers for the other two classes *below* the definition of the class but *above* the definition of the constructor. Example `A.h` file (untested):

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

template<typename T> class B;
template<typename T> class C;

template<typename T>
class A
{
    A(T const& x, T const& y, T const& z) {
        data[0] = x;
        data[1] = y;
        data[2] = z;
    }

    A(B<T> const& b);

    A(C<T> const& c);

    T x() {return data[0];}
    T y() {return data[1];}
    T z() {return data[2];}

    T data[3];
};

#include <B.h>
#include <C.h>

template<typename T>
inline A::A(B<T> const& b) :
    A(b.x(),b.y(),b.z())
{}

template<typename T>
inline A::A(C<T> const& c) :
    A(c.x(),c.y(),c.z())
{}

#endif
```

Repeat for classes B and C, and now you should be able to include any of `A.h`, `B.h`, and `C.h` and all three class definitions will be pulled in to meet the dependencies.

Comment: I am going to give this a shot.  I like having them in seperate because it seem 'cleaner' to me.  Would I be able to define a A.h, A.hxx, B.h, B.hxx, C.h, C.hxx and then just include all of these into a ABC.h file, in the order A.h, B.h, C.h, A.hxx, B.hxx, C.hxx.

Comment: @armstrhu: Yes, you can definitely do this if you want to keep the source code separate. What you actually can do is at the *bottom* of A.h, you can `#include` B.h and C.h, and *then* include the hxx files (which I assume will provide the constructor definitions). Then in B.h you can do the same, except include A.h at the bottom instead. Same for C.h. Then you should be able to include any of the .h headers individually and it will pull in all the dependencies. But this only works if the includes are at the bottom of the header files ;)

Comment: @armstrhu Actually I think you can accomplish this with only three headers, one for each class. I'll edit my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Obviously, such closely inter-related classes should live in the same header file. The solution proposed is the only sensible one.

Answer (score 3):

In that special case, I would try to remove the cyclic dependancy by using interfaces or superclasses. Basics: to remove the cyclic dependancy, each real class inherits from a superclass that only declares methods that are used in other classes. It might implement the ones that do not depend on other classes, or be a mere interface (only virtual methods). The only rule is that you must only use pointers or reference to object of other classes to avoid the slicing problem. Here it is simpler because all classes inherit from a common one, but in a more general use case, each could have its own superclass. It could be:

D.hxx

```
#ifndef _D
#define _D

template<typename T> 
class D {
public:
    virtual T x() const = 0;
    virtual T y() const = 0;
    virtual T z() const = 0;
    virtual ~D() = 0;    // better to add a virtual destructor...
};

#endif
```

that way, the other files become (say for A.hxx):

```
#include "d.h"

template<typename T>
class A: public D<T>
{
public:
    A(T const& x, T const& y, T const& z)
    {
        data[0] = x;
        data[1] = y;
        data[2] = z;
    }

    A(class D<T> const& d): A(d.x(), d.y(), d.z()) {} // for C++11 and above...

    T x() const { return data[0]; }
    T y() const { return data[1]; }
    T z() const { return data[2]; }

private:
    T data[3];
};
```

It works here, because you only use references of objects from other classes, so you only need the declarations. But I cannot know whether it can apply to your real use case.

Anyway as already said, the common superclass was only used here because it was simple, but you could use one interface or superclass per class

Comment: perhaps even more elegant with a delegating constructor for the second ctor. and the first ctor could do `: data{x,y,z} {}` and `data` be a `const` (and hence even `public`) member.

Comment: @Walter: you are right, but unfortunately I had to test with a non C++11 compiler that did not support delegating ctor. And I really wanted to test it before posting ;-) - Edited

Comment: This is a great solution.  Unfortunately, it wouldn't have worked for my use case. But good to consider for other use cases

Comment: @armstrhu: in fact, you do not need a common superclass. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to supply template argument to `B` and other classes.
Try this:

```
A(B<T> const& b) :      // B<T> should be better than B
 A(b.x(),b.y(),b.z())
{}
```

EDIT:

This compiles well:

```
template <class T>
class A;

template <class T>
class B;


template <class T>
class A
{
    void func(B<T> par) {
        par.func(this);
    }
};

template <class T>
class B
{
    void func(A<T> par) {
        par.func(this);
    }
};
```

EDIT2:

This compiles as well:

```
// A.h
template <class T>
class B;

template <class T>
class A
{
  public:
    void func(B<T>& par) {
        par.func(*this);
    }
};

// B.h
template <class T>
class A;

template <class T>
class B
{
    void func(A<T> par) {
        par.func(*this);
    }
};

// main.cpp
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int main()
{
    A<int> a;
    B<int> b;
    a.func(b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch, I fixed that.  This is not the actual code that I'm using, its something I concocted  to illustrate the issue I am having.  In my actual code, I do have the template parameters.

Comment: This wasn't an actual issue with my real code, just a little sloppiness on my part for this example.  I've updated the example. to include the template parameters.

Answer (score 0):

A first look, I don't think you can do this unless all three template classes are in the same header file due to:

1. Templates *usually* have to exist in totality in the header file.
2. You can't have cyclical dependencies, with or with out templates. To get around this, a class can have only pointers or references to a dependent class in it's header.  Then the class' cpp file can include the header of the dependent file.

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing correct templated type names. For example this constructor:

```
A(B const& b) :
```

should be:

```
A(B<T> const& b) :
```